# how to show magnifying glass when tap on UItextfield?

Tags: ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am developing registration page. In that 6 text fields and a button is there. When I tap last text field, keyboard will appear on screen. At that time last text field move up for visibility.

After fill all text fields keyboard is also dismissed. Now I want edit last text field using magnifying glass tap that text field move up and magnifying glass are showing in actual position where I tapped.

I want tap long press on text field. It will allow to magnifying glass for editing.
When tap normal press it text field moves up.

How can I solve this problem?